# Bootstrap button active and target styling not working

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm trying to customize my boostrap button colors, including on the hover state as well as when the user is busy clicking the button (button down) and after the user actually clicked the button. The sass that I have looks like this:

```
// Button styling
button.btn {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $lightOrange;
  border-color: $darkOrange;
}
button.btn:hover {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $mediumOrange;
  border-color: $darkOrange;
}
button.btn:active, button.btn:target {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $darkOrange;
  border-color: $darkOrange;
}
```

Now the default and hover states work great, but when the user clicks the mouse down on the button it defaults back to that gray color that is default with bootstrap. Also after the button has been clicked it remains that gray color instead of my `$darkOrange` that I specified. So in a nutshell, why doesn't `:active` and `:target` work?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you really shouldn't name variables to $white, $orange etc.. Name them $primary, $secondary etc.

Comment: Is that really best practice? Hmm.. naming the colors just seems a bit more intuitive to me. I'll give your suggestion a shot and see how it works out in future projects. Thanks :)

Comment: Try adding `!important`.

Comment: :active is working fine. Just after releasing your mouse button it works as :hover. :active is just for mouse press not for click.

Comment: This is irritating, sometimes !important is needed and other times not. It feels tacky that you have to use !important when adding custom styles to bootstrap.

Comment: I just went ahead and added !important to everything and now it works #YOLO

Comment: There's tons of articles explaining why you shouldn't, the most obvious one is that if you change it from the color in $white to black you also have to change the name of the variable in all the places you've used it. Thus making it completely useless to even use a variable in the first place.

Comment: Ahh I see! I'll definitely start doing that then. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Basically you need to make sure that you give your styles a higher specificity than Bootstrap's styles, without using `!important`.

The problem you're facing is that you use `button.btn` instead of just `.btn`. Since `button` is a global selector and it has a lower specificity than a class, the Bootstrap's styles will still rule over your custom styles for the same elements. Even if your file is included after Bootstrap.

To fix this simply change your code to this:

```
.btn {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $lightOrange;
  border-color: $darkOrange;
}
.btn:hover {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $mediumOrange;
  border-color: $darkOrange;
}
.btn:active, 
.btn:target {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $darkOrange;
  border-color: $darkOrange;
}
```

Comment: This was spot on for me. It was all about selector specificity. The funny thing is that Chrome's DevTools showed my CSS rule taking precedence, even though it wasn't. Once I made my selector more specific, this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

When you're targeting *bootstrap* elements always keep in mind to follow and override all the possible combinations.

And in your case you're targeting *bootstrap* `button`s, which are obviously having various combinations. Overriding them doesn't mean you've to use `!important` its just you've to use right `selector` in the right way.

As you've defined `.btn:active` but a `button` can be `:active` as well as `:focus` at the same point i.e. `.btn:active:focus`. So if you want to override its `:active` state then you've to look for all aspects as:

```
button.btn:active, 
button.btn:focus, 
button.btn:target, 
button.btn:active:focus { ... /*write your CSS here */ }
```

Here I've created a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/9414yoaw/1) also please have a look.

Hope it will help you solve your query and also clear your doubts regarding `!important`.